# android studio error while i create a project

Tags: android, android-studio

When i create a project in android studio I get an error like this

```
Error:
Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at http://gradle.org/docs/2.2.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Error:
Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Comment: There is no real question here. You should try to handle it by yourself and look around the web for answers.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check the java version installed in your system. 1.6 is better. If you have updated, uninstall the update and try again.
Be sure to check the SDK installed in your system also.
Good luck